# always getting stack.regionalFact error in aws-cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-cdk, aws-appsync

On any cdk command like `cdk-deploy` i get this error. I have created this project with `cdk innit app --language typescript`. my cdk version is 1.121.0

```
D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\aws-iam\lib\principals.ts:775
    return stack.regionalFact(
                 ^
TypeError: Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: stack.regionalFact is not a function.
Object creation stack:
  at stack traces disabled.
Object creation stack:
  at stack traces disabled..
    at ServicePrincipalToken.resolve (D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\aws-iam\lib\principals.ts:775:18)
    at RememberingTokenResolver.resolveToken (D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\core\lib\resolvable.ts:80:24)
    at RememberingTokenResolver.resolveToken (D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\core\lib\private\resolve.ts:286:18)
    at resolve (D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\core\lib\private\resolve.ts:212:51)
    at Object.resolve [as mapToken] (D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\core\lib\private\resolve.ts:119:77)
    at TokenizedStringFragments.mapTokens (D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\core\lib\string-fragments.ts:65:33)
    at RememberingTokenResolver.resolveString (D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\core\lib\resolvable.ts:99:22)
    at RememberingTokenResolver.resolveString (D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\core\lib\private\resolve.ts:290:23)
    at resolve (D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\core\lib\private\resolve.ts:170:48)
    at Object.resolve (D:\Unicorn\cdk\step03_graphQl\node_modules\@aws-cdk\core\lib\private\resolve.ts:119:77)
Subprocess exited with error 1
```

I'm just creating a graphQl api with AppSync and invoking lambda fucntion with it.

I have pin point where my error occurs by commenting all code and then uncommenting each construct one by one and then running `cdk deploy`

so this is the construct which gives error (when uncommented this, error occured)

```
const lambda_function = new lambda.Function(this, "LambdaFucntion", {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X, ///set nodejs runtime environment
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("lambda"), ///path for lambda function directory
  handler: "index.handler", ///specfic fucntion in specific file
  // timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(10), ///Time for function to break. limit upto 15 mins
});
```

Comment: It's likely a [cdk package version conflict](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18252).  Make sure all your cdk packages have the same version in `package.json`

Comment: `"dependencies": {
    "@aws-cdk/aws-appsync": "^1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-lambda": "^1.121.0",
    "@aws-cdk/core": "1.121.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.16"
  }`

Comment: @MuhammadMuaz don't use Comments as a chat. Update the question with an [edit] when answering queries in comments so your question details are all in one place. Comments aren't really part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"@aws-cdk/core": "1.121.0"` is missing the `^` before the version number, causing a CDK package versioning conflict.  The other packages (with the [carat symbol](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning#using-semantic-versioning-to-specify-update-types-your-package-can-accept)) have been updated to the latest minor release (when you last ran `npm update`), but `core` is stuck at v1.121.0.

Comment: tried that too. but it still gives error.

Comment: @MuhammadMuaz - You must also install the updated version with `npm update`.  If that does not work, perform a clean install: delete the `node_modules` folder, delete `package-lock.json`, run `npm install`.  Verify that all installed cdk packages have the same version with `npm list`.